# Bounding a function defined by an integral by an exponential function on $(1,\infty)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $x>1$ and set $I(x)=\int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{\alpha}}{\sinh^3(t)}e^{-x\coth(t)}dt$ where $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.
How to prove the following $\exists C_1,c>0,\forall x>1:|I(x)|\leq C_1 e^{- c x}$

Thanks a lot for any remark.

my Attempts: Since $\coth(t)\sim_\infty 1$, then $\exists \eta>0: t>\eta$ implies $e^{-x\coth(t)}\leq C e^{-x}$ and by integration we get the estimate for the seconde integral.(see below). But I can't do that for the first one.

$I(x)=\int^\eta_0 \frac{t^{\alpha}}{\sinh^3(t)}e^{-x\coth(t)}dt+\int^\infty_\eta \frac{t^{\alpha}}{\sinh^3(t)}e^{-x\coth(t)}dt$

Comment: Can you please include some more context, and some of your own attempts?

Comment: Actually if $x\gt0$ then $e^{-x\coth t}\lt e^{-x}$ everywhere on $t\ge0$, no need for some $C$ or some bound by $\eta$. Don't get lost in asymptotics

Comment: Thank you@FShrike. But the integral does not converge near 0 if we use your estimation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can show for $t <\eta$ with $\eta$ small enough, $\sinh^{3}(t)\geq At^3$ and $\coth(t)\geq B\frac{1}{t}$. Hence your first integral is bounded by $I=A\int_{0}^{\eta}t^{\alpha-3}e^{-x\frac{B}{t}}dt$. Now make the change of variable $u=\frac{1}{t}$ to get $I =A\int_{\frac{1}{\eta}}^{\infty}u^{1-\alpha}e^{-Bxu}du$. Now you can bound this term similarly to the second one and in the end you can probably optimize over $\eta$ (but note that your constants may depend on $\eta$)

**ADDED:**
Regarding your comment, we actually can by using the following tweak:
$I\leq e^{-B\frac{x}{2\eta}}A\int_{\frac{1}{\eta}}^{\infty}u^{1-\alpha}e^{-\frac{Bxu}{2}}du\\
\leq Ae^{-B\frac{x}{2\eta}}\int_{\frac{1}{\eta}}^{\infty}u^{1-\alpha}e^{-\frac{Bu}{2}}du$.

In the last inequality, I used your assumption $x>1$

Comment: Thank you. But we can't get the result since your integral is bounded by
$Ae^{-cx}\int_{\frac{1}{\eta}}^{\infty}u^{1-\alpha}du$ might not converge

Comment: see my new edits added

Comment: Yes I understand it. Thank you a lot for your help.